# function auth middleware node

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

Heei, im pretty new to js and node js and i could really use some help. I have this file where i export a middleware that handles the token

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/config");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    let decodeToken = jwt.verify(token, config.secrets.jwt);
    let id = decodeToken.id;
    let userType = decodeToken.userType;
    if (req.body.id && req.body.id !== id) {
      throw "Invalid user Id";
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } catch {
    res.status(401).json({
      error: new Error("Invalid request!"),
      message: "Unauthorized"
    });
  }
};
```

what I want is to wrap it into a function that takes as parameter the payload (the user id and user type), so i can access the user id and user type from any other file. Or if is there other way to export from here da user id and user type, to be visible so i can use them in controller files, for example. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access the used "from any other file." because the `user` is dynamic and is resolved only regarding the **context** of the HTTP request (your express middleware).

So what you need to do is add the `user` to the request context and extend the request object (the request object is the **context**).

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    let decodeToken = jwt.verify(token, config.secrets.jwt);
    let id = decodeToken.id;
    let userType = decodeToken.userType;
    if (req.body.id && req.body.id !== id) {
      throw "Invalid user Id";
    } else {
      req.user = decodeToken; // or any object that describe the user
      next();
    }
  } catch {
    ....
  }
};
```

Now you can access the request **context** in your controller and use the `user` as you see fit.

```
app.get('....', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.user);  // output { "id": XXX, userType: XXXX, ... }

   const userId = req.user.id;
   someService.someAction(userId, arg1, ....);
});
```

Comment: thank you!!! i tried this but i wasnt adding the user to the request correctly. you helped me, ty !